# Javascript not detecting number 79 or 16 in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm using `if(!(results[count].m._id in usedIdArray))` to determine whether or not an ID value already exists in an array. This if statement is in a for loop that iterates through 21 nodes in `results`. `usedIdArray` is just an array of integers and `results[count].m._id` is a number. `results[count].m` is generally like the following:

```
Node {
  _id: 79,
  labels: [ 'Block' ],
  properties:
   { blockID: '674511',
     upvotes: '4',
     x: '771.2391282095244',
     y: '224.80278118474385',
     type: 'link',
     url: 'https://stackoverflow.com' } }
```

There are other duplicate numbers in usedIdArray and `if(!(results[count].m._id in usedIdArray))` seems to detect those fine. For some reason it's only those nodes with the `_id` is 79 and 16 that cause the problem. I know there are duplicates of 3, 1, and several other numbers. When I run:

```
console.log(results[count].m._id);
console.log(usedIdArray);
```

I get:

```
3
[ 1 ]
79
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16 ]
16
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17 ]
79
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17, 16, 18 ]
79    
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17, 16, 18, 79, 19 ]
79
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17, 16, 18, 79, 19, 79, 20 ]
79
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17, 16, 18, 79, 19, 79, 20, 79, 21 ]
[ 1, 3, 2, 4, 13, 14, 16, 79, 17, 16, 18, 79, 19, 79, 20, 79, 21, 79, 22, 23, 24 ]
```

...with the last line being the full `usedIdArray`. I tried parsing the id value as an integer and as a string to no avail.

Comment: Why have you not mentioned 16 (that also duplicates)? Perhaps I don't understand the array output.

Comment: Ooops...didn't see that...I'll change it...

Comment: So you just removed the duplicate 16? I thought those were directly console.log()'d as the code just above infers. So does 16 not get detected as well as 79 or.... so very confusing.

Comment: perhaps it is time for a codepen or jsbin or something.

Comment: `in` looks for a property not a value. use `if(usedIdArray.indexOf(results[count].m._id) !== -1)` or something like that to check for values in an array.

Comment: 16 does not get detected as well as 79 the way I had it before, but `array.includes` worked perfectly for my purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `in` operator which returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.
Read more in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

You could use `array.includes` function to test if an element is contained within the list.

---

```js
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'fourth'];

console.log('one' in list); // -> false
console.log(list.includes('one')); // -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` looks for a property within an object. If you have 5 elements in an array, which is thought of as an object as 0: element1, 1: element2, etc.., and you ask if 0 in array then you will get true. But if you ask for element1 in array then you will get false.